# Retrieving all versions of an S3 Object

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm looking to move from version 1 of the AWS SDK for Ruby  to version 2.  However I've hit a snag with S3 object versioning.

Given a reference to an S3 object in Version 1 of the API you could retrieve all versions of just that object:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#versions-instance_method

However Version 2 of the API does not seem to replicate this feature: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html

Am I missing something?

Comment: so it looks like I could use the bucket API: _bucket.object_versions(:prefix => 'key').each {|version| ... }_  Is that really the only way using V2?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're correct, and this feature is missing from the V2 API.  I believe your only options are [`bucket.object_versions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html#object_versions-instance_method) or [`client.list_object_versions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#list_object_versions-instance_method).

You can retrieve all versions of an S3 object from the bucket like this:

```
# Retrieve Collection<ObjectVersion>
Aws::S3::Bucket.new('bucket-name')
  .object_versions(prefix: 'object-key')
  .reject { |version| version.key != 'object-key' }
```

I would *guess* that the Ruby SDK has made this change to better reflect the S3 REST API, where [versions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html) is its own subresource and objects don't have any knowledge of their own version history.